# Syntax error for (( $word = "y" || $word = ""Y" ))

Tags: bash, shell, sh

This is my shell script where i check whether the entered word is y or n; if any of these match then it will print an appropriate message.

```
 #! /bin/bash

read word

if (( $word = "y" || $word = "Y" ))
then    
    echo "YES"
elif (( $word = "n" || $word = "N" ))
then    
    echo "NO"
fi
```

But when I run this code then it  will give me a run-time error.

> ```
> Solution.sh: line 5: ((: y = y || y = Y : attempted assignment to non-variable (error token is "= Y ")
> Solution.sh: line 8: ((: y = n || y = N : attempted assignment to non-variable (error token is "= N ")
> ```

Comment: It's not compiled, it's just parsed.

Comment: `(( ... ))` is for *arithmetic* expressions, not string comparisons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want `[[ ... ]]`, not `((...))` (which is for *arithmetic* expressions)

```
#!/bin/bash

read word

if [[ $word = "y" || $word = "Y" ]]
then    
    echo "YES"
elif [[ $word = "n" || $word = "N" ]]
then    
    echo "NO"
fi
```

You can simplify this using pattern matching rather than strict equality testing

```
if [[ $word = [Yy] ]]
then
    echo "YES"
elif [[ $word = [Nn] ]]
then
    echo "NO"
fi
```

Or use a standard `case` statement

```
case $word in
  [Yy]) echo "YES" ;;
  [Nn]) echo "NO" ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using (very) non-standard syntax for the condition.  Consider the simplified:

```
#!/bin/bash

word=foo

if (( $word = 0 )) # || $word = "Y" ))
then
        echo "YES"
elif (( $word = 6 )) # || $word = "N" ))
then
        echo "NO"
fi

echo foo = $foo
```

This is valid syntax in the sense that bash will happily parse it, but it certainly does not do what you expect.  The `if (( $word = 0 ))` does not check if `$word` is equal to 0.  Instead, it assigns 0 to the variable named by `$word` (in this case, it assigns the variable `foo`) and decides whether that value is non-zero.  Since `$foo` is now zero, the `elif` portion is executed and 6 is assigned to `foo`.  The new value of `$foo` (6) is non-zero, so `NO` is echo'ed.

The values `y` and `Y` are treated as 0 in this context, but the `||` is a boolean operator here and the code `$word = 'y' || $word = 'Y'` is parsed as if it were `$word = ( 'y' || $word ) = 'Y'`, which incorrectly attempts to assign the the non-variable `'y' || $word`.  (Or maybe it is evaluating `'y' || $word` and trying to assign the variable `0`, which is not a valid name.  This feels like a philosophy question more than anything.  It's a parse error, so we probably shouldn't attempt to say what it is "trying" to do.) The error message is showing you that, and making its best attempt to indicate exactly where the error is.  It is valid syntax to write `(( $word = 'y' || ( $word = 'Y') ))`, which would assign `0` to `foo`, but this is certainly not the semantics you want.  Instead, your code should just be:

```
#!/bin/bash

read word

case $word in
y|Y) echo YES;;
n|N) echo NO;;
esac
```

If for some reason you really want to use the chained if/else instead of a `case`, the syntax you want is:

```
#! /bin/bash

read word

if test "$word" = y || test "$word" = Y; then   
    echo "YES"
elif test "$word" = n || test "$word" = N; then 
    echo "NO"
fi
```

You will often see `test` written as `[` with an additional trailing argument of `]`.  I consider that a horrible practice.

Also note that I've changed your quoting. It is generally a good idea to double quote variable interpolations, but there is no need to quote literal strings that do not contain special characters or whitespace.